# Assigning double values in C works unexpectedly

Tags: c, double, precision, arithmetic-expressions

Ive tried reading a lot of problems on SO and yet I cant seem to understand why my program reacts so strange..
I have this simple code trying to Implement sqrt function:

```
double sqrt,high,low,currNum;
scanf("%lf",&sqrt);
high = sqrt;
low = 0.0;
currNum = (high+low)/2.0;
```

after debugging and reaching the line after the last one, I have these results:
sqrt equals to 6(this is the number which was enterd..)
high equals to 0(????).
low equals 0.
currnum equals 6(???).

I just dont understnd the behavior of this values...
help please?

Comment: `sqrt` is also a math function for computing the square root.

Comment: [don't use reserved names.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sqrt.htm)

Comment: You don't show how you check these numbers.  Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're using a debugger to look at the values, you need to make sure that compiler optimizations are turned off. Otherwise, the debugger will get confused. OTOH, you could use `printf` to display the values, that will work regardless of the optimization level.

Comment: @dbush Yeah , that was rather of not that help, but if I saw that with `printf` I can see `high` getting value of `sqrt` .

Comment: Im using a debugger in-order to check this numbers. still no help?

Comment: @OmriShn Once print their values using `printf` and see , because with that only code, I get desired output .

Comment: after using printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", high,low,currNum,squareRoot); im getting 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000. I dont know what compiler optimizations is so I guess the answer is yes? @user3386109

Comment: explain please? @user3386109 is there a guide?

Comment: Further to @user3386109's comment, a common optimization is to combine two variables that always have the same value. The compiler may be using `sqrt` (the variable) instead of `high` in the `currNum` calculation, and not bothering with the copy to `high`.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant seem to understand why my program reacts so strange.. I have this simple code...

I'll explain your program. This line reserves four spaces in memory where each space is a size of a double, but no specific value is assigned to any. You can then expect random values for each.

```
double sqrt,high,low,currNum;
```

If you want to make each value zero to begin with, use this line instead:

```
double sqrt=0,high=0,low=0,currNum=0;
```

This line reads and accepts a numerical input that is of the double type and stores the value in the sqrt variable:

```
scanf("%lf",&sqrt);
```

This sets high to the value of sqrt:

```
high = sqrt;
```

This sets low to be 0.0:

```
low = 0.0;
```

This calculates the sum of what the user typed in then divides the total in half (a.k.a. by 2) then stores the result in the currNum variable:

```
currNum = (high+low)/2.0;
```

> after debugging and reaching the line after the last one, I have these results: sqrt equals to 6(this is the number which was entered..) high equals to 0(????). low equals 0. currnum equals 6(???). I just dont understand the behavior of this values... help please?

Because you set "low" to be zero, what you made here is a program that calculates half of the number the user typed in.

> ...trying to Implement sqrt function:

I'm sure if you use a C library you'll get a good square root function. This program prints the square root of 9.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  double x=sqrt(9);
  printf("%lf",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is merely a part of the code which acts strangely.. the rest of the implemention is ot mentioned since the problem is not there..

Comment: I'm just confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. If its to calculate the square root of a number, then use my code in my answer as a starting point.